# Import CV in netbeans to run python program

Tags: java, python, opencv, netbeans

i want to run the below code

how can i import OPENCV in this python program to run in netbeans8.1
how can i import OPENCV in this python program to run in netbeans8.1

````
import cv2

# load images
image1 = cv2.imread("leftImage.jpg")
image2 = cv2.imread("rightImage.jpg")

# compute difference
difference = cv2.subtract(image1, image2)

# color the mask red
Conv_hsv_Gray = cv2.cvtColor(difference, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, mask = cv2.threshold(Conv_hsv_Gray, 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV |cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
difference[mask != 255] = [0, 0, 255]

# add the red mask to the images to make the differences obvious
image1[mask != 255] = [0, 0, 255]
image2[mask != 255] = [0, 0, 255]

# store images
cv2.imwrite('diffOverImage1.png', image1)
cv2.imwrite('diffOverImage2.png', image1)
cv2.imwrite('diff.png', difference)```

i want to compare two images using the abouve python program.how to import OPENCV in this python program to run in netbeans8.1 . installed python plugin in netbeans.
how to import OPENCV in this python program to run in netbeans8.1 . installed python plugin in netbeans.
````